# c# Sorting an array with IComparable Interface

Tags: c#, arrays, icomparable

I have a jobArray array with 5 jobs that contain a `description`, `hours needed to complete`, and an `hourly pay that a user enters`.

I need to sort the array when it prints by ascending order of the total fee `(hours * hourly pay)`.

The assignment requires I use the `IComparable interface` when doing so but I'm unsure how to use it. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Here is my `job` class

```
class Job : IComparable
{

    public Job(string description, int hours, double hourRate, double fee)
    {
        Description = description;
        hoursToComplete = hoursToComplete;
        hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
        totalFee = totalFee;

    }
```

This is the interface I've done to compare totalFees

```
    public int CompareTo(Job o)
    {
        int returnVal;
        Job temp = (Job)o;
        if (this.totalFee > temp.totalFee)
            returnVal = 1;
        else
            if (this.totalFee < temp.totalFee)
                returnVal = -1;
            else
                returnVal = 0;
        return returnVal;

    }
```

I'm unsure what do to from here as to sorting the `jobs` when they print out by `total fees`.

Comment: I think you did it correct. Now just add the objects of this class to a list and use sort() method.

Comment: Your code will not compile. There are a number of obvious errors in your code that has nothing to do with IComparable or sorting. You should first attempt to fix it before trying to do anything more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the working version of your code:

```
class Job : IComparable<Job>
{
    public string Description { get; set;}

    public int HoursToComplete { get; set;}

    public double HourlyRate { get; set;}

    public double TotalFee { get; set;}

    public Job(string description, 
               int hoursToComplete, 
               double hourlyRate, 
               double totalFee)
    {
        Description = description;
        HoursToComplete = hoursToComplete;
        HourlyRate = hourlyRate;
        TotalFee = totalFee;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Job otherJob)
    {
        int returnVal;

        if (this.TotalFee > otherJob.TotalFee)
            returnVal = 1;
        else
            if (this.TotalFee < otherJob.TotalFee)
            returnVal = -1;
        else
            returnVal = 0;

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Now since you have implemented `IComparable<Job>`, then on the given `List<Job>`, just call `Sort`, which will automatically call `Job` class `CompareTo`, instead of object class.
Also note I have used the generic version `IComparable<Job>`, instead of `IComparable`, to avoid unncessary type-casting

Comment: thank you. would i call it when i print out the array? when i try to call .sort it does not appear on the intellisense.

Comment: Call `ArrayObject.ToList()`, then call `Sort` on the List

Comment: You can simplify CompareTo to a one-liner.

`return this.TotalFee - otherJob.TotalFee`

Comment: In this case true, but will not work as expected in all the cases, where multiple fields are involved, therefore used the standard comparison notation, modifying the OP code. Nonetheless thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you override "compareTo" method, and if you call "sort", the overrideen method is automatically called.

Here is a good example from microsoft for arrays.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320727

Below is a an example (pseudo code)  of "LIST"

```
List<Job> list = new List<Job>();

list.Add(new Job() { //Intialize arguments });
list.Add(new Job() { //Intialize arguments });
list.Add(new Job() { //Intialize arguments });
list.Add(new Job() { //Intialize arguments });
list.Add(new Job() { //Intialize arguments });

// Uses IComparable.CompareTo()
list.Sort();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try CompareTo function as given below:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
     job tempList = (job)obj;
     return tempList.totalFee.CompareTo(totalFee);
}
```

Then call your method.

```
list.Sort()
```